Fetch from HTML template in spring boot
I am trying to fetch an api endpoint "latest image url" from Rest api controller in spring. The Html template is
<div class="image-container">
        <img class="image-div" id="latest-image" />
        <script th:inline="javascript">
          async function fetchLatestImageUrl() {
            try {
              const response = await fetch(
                "http://localhost:8080/latest-image-url?folderPrefix=/8HMJJA126Y/1/",
                {
                  method: "GET",
                  credentials: "include", // This will include cookies in the request if needed
                }
              );
              console.log(response);
              if (response.ok) {
                const url = await response.text();
                document.getElementById("latest-image").src = url;
              } else {
                console.error("Failed to fetch the latest image URL");
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error fetching the latest image URL:", error);
            }
          }

          // Call the function to fetch and display the image when the page loads
          fetchLatestImageUrl();
        </script>

my restapi controller:

    @GetMapping("latest-image-url")
    public String getLatestImageUrl(@RequestParam String folderPrefix) {
        System.out.println("prefix:" + folderPrefix);
        return s3LatestImage.listObjectsInFolder(folderPrefix);
    }

s3LatestImage service:

@Service
public class s3LatestImage {
     public String listObjectsInFolder(String folderPrefix) {
        System.out.println(folderPrefix);
        //presigned url for latest image
        return "https url";
    }
}

when i run the code i get 404 error. I can call other api endpoint but fail to fetch url for this one.
error log
i tried reconfiguring the code but i am at the same state.
